# I would like to know the path to save the file when it is stored in memory

Tags: python

I would like to know the path to save the file when it is stored in memory.

Is it possible?

If possible, please let me know how to do it.

Comment: Hey, your question is really vague and does not provide any details about your problem Please check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's very unclear what you want. Please rephrase it. Try to provide examples

Comment: A file object has a `name` attribute, but that is merely the path that you used to access the file.  In general, files do not have unique names, and there can be many paths to the same file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear. I assume you mean something like this:

```
path = r'C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Test.txt'

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    print(f.name)
```

Using a `with open` loop, the path of file is saved as the `name` attribute of the `TextIOWrapper` object, here `f`.

You could also have a look at the `os.path` module, which included many utility functions related to filepaths, e.g., `os.path.abspath`.

Comment: hi @Ben Zeen, Thank you today I learned this new thing